# Format Interactive Placeholder Text in HTML Input Date via CSS

Tags: html, css, date

> This seems like a basic problem but I'm having trouble finding a solution on Google for some reason, a lot of the answers I find either don't preserve interactivity or refer to jQuery.

What I would like to do is to simply change the interactive text to another format, e.g., `dd/mm/aaaa`.

[image: Input Date formatted to English date]

However, I would **not** like it to be something like this — which did **not** work —:

```html
<input type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"/>
```

Because then I would have to do it for every date input in my application. If I could do it with CSS, it would be much more programmatic.

Comment: The date format is determined by the localisation settings of the user's browser. Giving a date format which isn't the one the user is used to probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: I agree that that default is very sensible, but I find it very weird and underwhelming that there isn't a simple way to override it in HTML or CSS.